# set ng-readonly="true" on table row after saving

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using angular to populate and edit data in a table, this works as expected however I would like to be able to mark a row as ng-readonly false when 'Edit' is clicked (which also works fine) and then to set the row to ng-readonly true again after clicking 'Update' (which is the part I cannot figure out).

I have tried setting this from the angular controller using $scope.isReadOnly = true however this does not have any effect.

The table would have a button 'Edit' which when clicked makes the row editable (readonly=false) and also hides the button using ng-show, the 'Update' button then displays and on click should submit ng-model="webUser" and set isReadOnly back to true which then makes the row not editable and replaces the'Update' button with the 'Edit' button.

[image: User table]

This is the table

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <h2>Web Users</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="webUser in webUsers track by webUser.userId">
            <td><input ng-readonly="true" type="text" ng-model="webUser.userId" /></td>
            <td><input ng-readonly="isReadOnly" type="text" ng-model="webUser.statusValue" /></td>
            <td><input ng-readonly="isReadOnly" type="email" ng-model="webUser.emailAddress" /></td>
            <td><button ng-hide="!isReadOnly" ng-disabled="!isReadOnly" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="isReadOnly = false">Edit</button></td>
            <td><button type="submit" ng-hide="isReadOnly" ng-readonly="true" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="UpdateWebUser(webUser)">Update</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And the AngularJS code in the controller is:

```
    $scope.UpdateWebUser = function (webUser) {
    $scope.isReadOnly = true;
};
```

The only way I have been able to do this so far is to set the variable of isReadOnly directly using ng-click="isReadOnly = false/true" however doing this means I cannot call the controller using ng-click on the same button and so I would have to use ng-submit and that would require removing the table and instead using a form which is made to look like it's a table which is not the way I want to do this.

Can anyone please advise a way I can achieve this using angular?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your requirement, you need an extra variable to separate edit and non-edit mode **per user**. One way to achieve that is by adding a boolean `edit` in each user object and toggle this value to make fields read-only or not:

```
<div class="container text-center">
<h2>Web Users</h2>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="webUser in webUsers track by webUser.userId">
    <td><input ng-readonly="true" type="text" ng-model="webUser.userId" /></td>
    <td><input ng-readonly="!webUser.edit" type="text" ng-model="webUser.statusValue" /></td>
    <td><input ng-readonly="!webUser.edit" type="email" ng-model="webUser.emailAddress" /></td>
    <td><button ng-hide="webUser.edit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="webUser.edit = true">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button type="submit" ng-hide="!webUser.edit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="UpdateWebUser(webUser)">Update</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Controller with no change:

```
$scope.UpdateWebUser = function(webUser) {
    console.log(webUser);
    webUser.edit = false;
  };
```

Check that working demo: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9ewv4dku/15/)